# Post value from view to controller asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox

This is a part of my view :

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm())
       { %>
            <input type="checkbox" name="ali" value="123" />
            <%: Html.CheckBox("ali1") %>
                <a href='<%:Url.Action("DeleteSelected", "Product", new { @ShopID = ViewBag.shopIDempty } ) %>'>dddd</a>
                <input type="submit" onclick='<%: Url.Action("DeleteSelected", "Product", new { @ShopID = ViewBag.shopIDempty } ) %>' />
     <%} %>
```

and this the controller :

```
        public ActionResult DeleteSelected(FormCollection collection, int ShopID)
    {
        var t = collection.GetValue("ali");
        var t2 = collection["ali"];
        var selectCB11 = collection.GetValue("ali");

        var t1 = collection.GetValue("ali1");
        var t21 = collection["ali1"];
        var selectCB121 = collection.GetValue("ali1");
        //...
    }
```

But nothing passes to my variables and all of them are null always. What is wrong?

Comment: What is the purpose of the submit button with a URL in it's onclick event handler?

Comment: Actually I have some pictures in a page. The user want to delete some of them. User selects some pictures with checkbox. There is a checkbox beside of each picture. then the must click the delete button. Now I want to send the selected checkbox to Delete action and delete pictures. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clicking a link will never post back to the server, or redirecting client-side from a submit button will also not cause the postback.  Any input values like the checkbox will never be sent to the server.  You need to use a form with the submit button, and let the submit naturally postback to the server.

Or, you can use JQuery's $.ajax to create a JavaScript post statement to do this asynchronously, [like these examples](http://blog.bobcravens.com/2009/11/ajax-calls-to-asp-net-mvc-action-methods-using-jquery/).